# Skrollr - scroll frame effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, skrollr

I would like to create an effect similar with the one on http://www.squarespace.com/ (the computer change images while you scroll) but i don't understand how they managed to make it so smooth. So far i have this:
http://yonescat.com/yonescat2016 and i definitely miss something.

Is there any example or tutorial for such an effect?
Is this technique has a particular name so i can search for it?
Can you give me some ideas on how to achieve something like that?

Thank You!